# Seeking rasters about annual snow cover duration and nightlight over Europe

Tags: download, data

I am looking for two type of rasters: one about the annual snow cover duration (in days or percentage) and the other one about the annual night light intensity, both over Europe.

I tried looking for them on the Internet, and while I found only monthly layers for snow covers (I should use the layers from 2012 up to now, I would like not to do the mean of more than 100 layers), I cannot find any layers about night light.

Can you provide me with some links to download this kind of data?